# Wilcoxon rank-sum or t-test with a single subject in a group

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions

I'm just wondering if I have Group A (N=20) and group B (N=1), does it valid to do a statistical test, such as (independent) Wilcoxon rank sums or independent t-test? Note that group A and B are independent (different population).

Given that these tests works on class distribution, it seems that it wouldn't be correct to draw class distribution from only 1 sample. Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: @Dave2e no, they're completely independent (hence independent tests). Thanks, I added this info in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use independent t-test for this because you can not compute variance when $n=1$. You can compute a Wilcoxon rank-sum test, but it will be uninformative : you could instead compute how many times "Group B" was over Group A.

Better, compute the z-score of "Group B" based on mean and variance of Group A, then see the probability of the value. It will tell you how likely is "Group B" compared to Group A.

Comment: So the essence of doing those tests is to check on the p-value of the variables and we're going to analyse on the significant variables. I will use your suggestion on z-score to compare "Group B" and Group A after getting those significant peaks. Given this, my next question is that - how valid is the p-value of wilcoxon rank-sum test in this case to get significant features? Also, another quick question, since what we do here is wilcoxon (median), what do you think of computing z-score on median and median absolute deviation?

Comment: Probably not very reliable. The wikipedia entry suggest that "for sample sizes above ~20, approximation using the normal distribution is fairly good". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test (see calculations)

Comment: So any suggestion on how to select most significant features? Should I use the z-score method, and filter based on the "Group B"'s z-score (since it shows how much it deviates from mean/median, if median absolute deviation)? Using the z-score seems to be quiet subjective though, since there is no rule-of-thumb threshold (as far as I know) for a feature to be significant (vs p-value < 0.05 in stats tests).

Comment: Not sure to understand your comment. You can use usual critical z-scores like + or - 1.64 (90% confidence) or 1.96 (95% confidence).

Comment: Thanks! That's really helpful. Any thoughts on modified z-score (using median + median absolute dev) for data with some outliers?